# .Net CF Initialization Error

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, .net-2.0, windows-ce, windows-mobile-5.0

I have a windows CE app that built it with MS VS 2008 smart device .NET 3.5.
after transmit this app to hand held i see below error.

```
.Net CF Initialization Error
```

"the application field to load required components. if the .NET compact framwork is install on a storage card , please insure ...."
you can see the compelete error in below picture  :

[image]

can i improve my device .Net version without change windows CE  ?
or i have to recreate this app with .NET 2.0 ?

Comment: CF 3.5 should work.  Did you install it via CAB file?

Comment: No, i just transmit Bin Folder contents to Hand  held , and see this error!but before it do this with new version windows CE (6.0) and worked fine

Comment: The device probably shipped with CF 1.0 or 2.0, so you have to deploy 3.5 if you're compiled against that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check, which CF version is installed on the device, run cgacutil.exe in windows dir.

The device (an Intermec CN4, according to the title in the screenshot) comes with Windows Mobile 6.1. But I am not sure, if it comes with CF2 or CF3 pre-installed.

Answer (score 0):

Bellow Location has two Folders

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\

1. v2.0
2. v3.5

Check All Reference's paths in Solution Explorer. same version should be selected for all reference's from the correct folder as the version you selected on the time of Project creation.

As Windows CE forms are available in both Versions.

in v2.0 as Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms
in v3.5 as  Microsoft.Windowsce.Forms

If Started the Project with .Net v3.5 and added Reference of Windows ce forms from v2.0 folder. the OS will ask for .NET CF Initialization .